# i have installed composer and now need to install php_ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, composer-php, ffmpeg-php

hey all i have successfully downloaded and installed composer on my windows7 64bit wamp server and i need to install php_ffmpeg by composer.
i don't have any idea i have already read their documentation but it is not so clear ?
please let me know the next step.

i got the details about the composer and php_ffmpeg from this link

```
https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg
```

here is the code that i get when i update,require and install composer by cmd

```
C:\Windows\system32>composer update
 Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Nothing to install or update
 Generating autoload files

 C:\Windows\system32>composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg
    Using version ^0.6.0 for php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg
   ./composer.json has been updated
     Loading composer repositories with package information
     Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
     Nothing to install or update
      Generating autoload files

       C:\Windows\system32>composer install
      Loading composer repositories with package information
      Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
       Nothing to install or update
        Generating autoload files
```

here is the screenshot of my wamp server and installed modules

[image]

Comment: What's unclear exactly? They even provide the exact JSON data so you can simply copy and paste into your `composer.json` file.

Comment: i have done till adding the require code to json file now what to do so hat i can see the module added to my php.ini file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to do that,

1. From command line

```
composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg
```

2. Add to "require" section into your composer.json

```
  "require": {
      "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "dev-master"
  }
```

and execute

```
composer install
```

Comment: Thankyou very much sir, i highly apprecate your help .i added it to composer.jsoon file how do i execute the install again ? by exe file that i downloaded ??

Comment: @sonamSharma No, after you added it to composer.json, got to terminal (command line), type composer install and hit enter. Composer will download and install all dependencies.

Comment: it says :- 
    
        C:\Windows\system32>composer install
         Loading composer repositories with package information
          Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
          Nothing to install or update
          Generating autoload files

Comment: sir i have added the response that i get when i update,require and install the composer please tell  me is this the expected response?? have i successfully installed the composer ??? please.
And your reply is really helping me out ..

Comment: @sonamSharma, check your vendor directory... it looks like you already installed it. in your **vendor** directory you should find **php-ffmpeg** directory

Comment: if by vector directory you mean this path "wamp\apps\phpsysinfo3.1.12\sample\distrotest\Vector" then there is only one file named 647.0.txt. And if i have already installed this then why it is not showing to my phpinfo() page or in the list of installed modules ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84349/discussion-between-sonam-sharma-and-eugene-nezhuta).